# How does one delete a stream depot in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

Basically what I want to do is delete a depot off the server. I have access to both P4Admin and the P4Helix.

Now I understand that I must first delete all workspaces then streams then delete the depot. But I am looking for a workaround to this process (personally I find it stupid, what if someone left the company and doesn't want to cooperate?), is there one?

Can I force delete a depot and its Streams without going to every single possible user that may have used this depot and ask them to delete workspaces for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First, obliterate all the files in the depot.
- Next, delete all the clients of all the streams in the depot.
- Next, delete all the streams in the depot.
- Last, delete the depot.

This sort of thing is always easier to do via the CLI than P4Admin, IMO.  Here are the four command lines that do those four things:

```
p4 obliterate -y //yourdepot/...
p4 -F "clients -S %stream%" streams //yourdepot/... | p4 -F "client -df %domainName%" -x - run | p4 -x - run
p4 -F "stream -d %stream%" streams //yourdepot/... | p4 -x - run
p4 depot -d yourdepot
```

Note that you need admin/super access to run most of these commands.  `p4 client -df` is what allows you to force the deletion of a client that you don't own.

You may also need to run the third command (the one that deletes the streams) a couple of times, since child streams need to be deleted before their parents.  You *could* write a clever script that does a graph search and then deletes the streams in a bottom-up order, but it's a lot easier to just brute force it by running multiple passes, since each time through you'll take out at least one entire layer of the hierarchy.  :)

(I agree it'd be nice it there was more of a one-shot way of doing this, but the command line at least makes it easy to plumb queries together so you don't need to hunt each thing down manually.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a chance I can do this using the GUI mode instead of the CLI?

Comment: As far as I know, to do this in the GUI you need to click through each workspace/stream individually and delete them one at a time.

Comment: Thank you VERY Much, it turned out I couldn't see Workspaces because it was auto-filtered to the ones I have. When I removed that I saw all the Workspaces and I nuked the one that prevented Streams from being deleted. I was able to kill the depot finally and not needing any of the users.