# Removing child streams to delete Perforce stream depot

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I have the following situation:
We created a stream depot and started using it. After that it was figured out that we want a different name for the stream depot, so we just created a new correctly named one and copied everything from the old depot. it's already in use for quite some time.

Now we want to get a rid of the old wrongly named stream depot.
I obliterated contents of the depot via Perforce *Helix Admin client* (GUI) then tried to `Delete Depot` and it replied with 
`Depot 'depotname' is the location of existing streams; cannot delete until they are removed.`

So, I moved to P4 CLI to list and remove existing streams:

`[root@linuxbox]# p4 streams //depotname/...
 Stream //depotname/main mainline none 'main'
 Stream //depotname/main.dev virtual //depotname/main 'main.dev'
 [root@linuxbox]# p4 stream -df //depotname/main
 Stream '//depotname/main' has child streams; cannot delete until they are removed.`

So, the question is how can I delete those child streams from the stream depot? (what should I use instead of `p4 stream -df //depotname/main`)? 
Will I be able to just delete the depot after that?
And wouldn't it impact other depots on the same p4d server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one delete a stream depot in Perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888229/how-does-one-delete-a-stream-depot-in-perforce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57892035/3799759

You need to delete **all** of the streams in the depot, not just the mainline stream.  The steps described in that answer should do the job.

For your specific case, you could do it manually with:

```
p4 stream -d //depot/main.dev
p4 stream -d //depot/main
p4 depot -d depot
```

but only if you've already deleted all the clients of those streams (again, see the other answer, which covers that too).

Comment: Thank you Sam, that actually helped me. The depot deleted successfully after deleting child streams 
`p4 stream -d //depot/main.dev
p4 stream -d //depot/main`